# Push doesn't work after back button?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm working on an app that scans a barcode and segues into a new view controller after a scan is found. However, if the user clicks the back button (navigation controller, root view controller is a main menu, but is [probably] irrelevant), the view controller will not segue again. So it segues forward to view controller 3 the first time the app runs, but upon hitting "back" and returning to VC 2, it won't segue to VC 3 again. Is there something I'm missing? I do set the handler in `viewDidLoad`:

```
        self.barcodesHandler = { barcodes in
            if(self.handler_flag) {
                var barcode = barcodes[0]
                println("Barcode found: type=" + barcode.type + " value=" + barcode.stringValue)
                self.bcode = barcode.stringValue
                self.handler_flag=false
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("push", sender: nil)
            }
        }
```

And the segue:

```
override public func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController
    destinationVC.setText = bcode



}
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: is it a tapbar application template?

Comment: @ÖzgürErsil, no, it's a single view.

Comment: i think you should put your code in `viewDidAppear:` function too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("push", sender: nil)
```

Instead of `nil` use `self`